# Typescript optional object

Tags: typescript

I want to use optional object like Java.

I want to use it like this:

```
car.engie.plug
```

I expect that it return null if `car` or `engine` is null and not throw an exception.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no language feature for this, but you can use simple existing language features to achieve the same result...

```
if (car && car.engine && car.engine.plug) {
    return car.engine.plug;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

You could also use the [null object pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/null-object-pattern.html) to ensure you never have to handle this situation.